# Folder accessible in Teminal but not in Finder

Tags: macbook-pro, ios, permission, high-sierra

I have a new Mac Book, and I moved data using Time Machine.  Since I have a new username (raj.more) on the new Mac Book, the restored data is sitting in it's own profile folder structure (rmore).

I am currently trying to move all of my music back into iTunes.  However, the old folder `/users/rmore/music` cannot be accessed in `Finder`.  I get an error saying "You don't have permission to access the content".

Funnily enough I can open the folder in Terminal, and browse to it without any issues at all and copy files.

How do I fix this (it applies to Documents, Downloads, and other folders as well)?

Comment: These folders may all be in iCloud. Go to the icloud drive and see if you can access them that way.

Comment: have you ensured you're the admin?

Comment: I just set up the new macbook myself - I am ad admin by default, right?  Also, if I don't have permissions, how can i browse into the folder in Terminal, but not in Finder?

Comment: not being real good with terminal I am not sure of the exact options but you should be able to "sudo chmod -R" to change the ownership of the files and folders so that your current username owns those file, which is currently does not.